# How to terminate Database connections created using dynamic JDBC credentials?

Tags: oracle-adf

I followed the below article to create dynamic JDBC connection.

[How to support dynamic JDBC credentials](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/dynamicjdbchowto-101755.html)

I was able to do it properly and when a user try to login a JDBC connection created successfully with their credentials.

But I also want these connections to terminate while the users logout. I am doing session.invalidate() during logout but its not terminating the database connections.

The dynamic connections are retained even after the application is undeployed. They get removed only if I stop the web-logic server.
The timeouts set for the application module are not applied to these connections. Please help me if there is a way to close these dynamic JDBC connection during logout.

I am using JDeveloper 12.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADF, you do not manage the db connection directly. The Application Module manages the connection to be used by referring to a DB Connection pool JNDI name that is provided by the Application Server.

Since it is expensive to create a db conn, the App server, WebLogic for example, maintains a set of db connections in a DB conn pool. When an ADF App Module needs a connection it is given one from this pool. When the user ends the (ADF) session, the connection is returned to the pool to be (re)used by another session. You might wish to start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/b31974/bcampool.htm#ADFFD1333) with the docs which explains this. WLS docs will describe how to manage the db conn pool.

Bottom line is you should not be opening/closing db connections programmatically from within an ADF App.